# Is there a way to disallow changing a method signature in subclasses?

Tags: python

We are writing an application that uses drivers for different implementations of the same methods (through class overloading). The problem is that we can change a method signature in the subclass, so that it breaks other drivers if they are not modified accordingly.

I'll put a simple example below:

```py
class Driver:
    name = "unknown"

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    def printmsg(self, msg: str):
        print(self.name, 'says', msg)


class Impl1(Driver):
    def printmsg(self, msg: str):
        """ overloading with the same signature """
        print(f"{self.name}: {msg}")


class Impl2(Driver):
    def printmsg(self, msg: str, more: str):
        """ overloading with another signature """
        print(self.name, 'says', msg, 'and', more)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    impl1 = Impl1(name="toto")
    impl1.printmsg("message")

    impl2 = Impl2(name="toto")
    impl2.printmsg("message")
```

Results:

```
toto: message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/class_method.py", line 27, in <module>
    impl2.printmsg("message")
TypeError: Impl2.printmsg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'more'
```

I'd like to prevent the changing of method signatures in different implementations to help preventing this kind of error. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: the best way is to use static analysis tools like `mypy` or `pyright`